# how to wrap/split long expression?

Tags: c#

I have an expression and 2 ways of splitting it:

```
List<string> list = 
            collection.Select(
                control => SearchForControl(
                    control, someOtherParameters)).Select(
                        customControl => customControl.InnerText).ToList();

List<string> list = collection.
                    Select(control => SearchForControl(control, someOtherParameters)).
                    Select(customControl => customControl.InnerText).ToList();
```

What is more readable/better?
Where to put dots in the second case: at the beginning or end of the line?

Comment: I would say that second one is better. About dots i prefer when their are at beggining (actually im forced to do it that way due to stylecop settings :)).

Comment: The 1st one has inconsistent indentation. This question is also off-topic.

Comment: If I had to choose, my personal preference is for the first case for me.  The second scans too much like a method call with args, whereas the first emphasizes the nesting.  Dots at the end, please!  I'd also probably break up the expression a bit more, as it's a bit "busy".

Comment: This is not an engineering problem. This is a style question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think pretty much everyone would consider the second to be more readable, since it justifies the query operations (`Select`, `Where`, etc) prettily one below the other.

For the dots, I would place them at the start of the line like this:

```
var list = collection
               .Select(control => SearchForControl(control, someOtherParameters))
               .Select(customControl => customControl.InnerText)
               .ToList();
```

The reason is that it's easier to copy/paste lines from or to this expression without breaking the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is a style question, so you'll find there are as many possible answers as there are coders in the world.

I prefer the second approach myself, but with the dots at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
List<string> list = collection.Select(control => 
    SearchForControl(control, someOtherParameters).InnerText).ToList();
```

You don't need two selects.

If you do need to wrap things like in your second case I would put the dots at the beginning of the line so you can see the line is a continuation.

Answer (score 0):

For linq, I find it reads easiest if you line up the linq methods like this (with dots at begining):

```
List<string> list =
  collection
    .Select(
      control => SearchForControl(control, someOtherParameters))
    .Select(
      customControl => customControl.InnerText)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-opinionated:

```
List<string> list = 
  collection.
  Select(control => SearchForControl(control, someOtherParameters)).
  Select(customControl => customControl.InnerText).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer ReSharper automatic formatting with default style rules. This point was grown up from the experience of developing a big project within a team of 20 developers. :)